# Is there anyway to create a link via a webview that opens a part of your application?

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

For example: The facebook app is basically just a webview using html5, so how does it link to things like the default message editor when you try to write something on someone's wall? I know part of the app is probably using Three20. So are they just linking to that part of the app using their app url? (fb://profile/122605446 for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this using the `UIWebView` delegate method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method.  You will need to use a custom URL scheme to trigger your custom code, otherwise you let it pass through as normal. so in your example `fb` is the custom scheme. The use the rest of the URL to navigate to the profile screen for user 122605446.

Here is some sample code to help:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSString *scheme = [url scheme];
    if ([scheme isEqualToString:@"fb"]) {
        //Do something with the rest of the url and take any action you like.
    }
    else {
        return YES;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could do that. Look at the [UIWebViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a), specifically `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`

The `NSURLRequest` will let you know when a link is clicked. You could have specific args in the link & depending on the args you could custom handle what views to open in your iOS app. or you would simply return `NO` on this method if you want to prevent the request from loading.

Answer (score 1):

The UIWebViewDelegate has a method called `webView:shouldStartLoadingRequest:navigationType`. You can use this method to intercept certain links, button clicks, etc. You can create your own link that way, too:

`<a href="myApp://dosomething">Click!</a>` The second argument of the delegate method now has a NSURLRequest for which the URL is "myApp://dosomething".

Answer (score 0):

You could simply register a number of url types (or just one, fb://) in your app.

Then you parse the url and open different parts of the application based on the URL you received.

See http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html for a good overview and tutorial.

(It does not really matter that the views in the app are written in HTML5 in this case.)